# User cannot query cross-database, despite having permissions for both databases

Tags: sql-server, permissions, sql-server-2017

SQL Server 2017 Enterprise (14.0.3356.20), running on Windows Server 2016.

I have a situation where an application's user needs to join on a table in a separate database in the same instance, but I'm getting permissions errors when I try to run anything cross-database.  Basically, what it boils down to is that this works fine:

```
use DB2
EXECUTE AS user = 'domain\appUser'
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM dbo.Table
REVERT
```

But this doesn't:

```
use DB1
EXECUTE AS user = 'domain\appUser'
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM DB2.dbo.Table
REVERT
```

I get the following error on the second query:

```
Msg 916, Level 14, State 1, Line 3
The server principal "domain\appUser" is not able to access the database "DB2" under the current security context.
```

The user is mapped to both databases.  There are plenty of places elsewhere in our other applications that we have used this same kind of cross-database join, and they work fine.  Logged in as my admin user, this also works fine of course. I admittedly don't know too much about permissions in SQL Server, and this one has me stumped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an artifact of your testing methodology.  You impersonated a user.  A user is a database-level principal.

Instead impersonate the login, or test with the target identity actually connecting to SQL Server.